# Why there is a memory leak using SnapKit?

Tags: ios, snapkit

I'am using SnapKit 3.2.0. When I use snapkit in my project, it shows a memory issue in the Memory Graph of Xcode.

[image]

I created a very simple project at [here](https://github.com/GF-Destiny/TestUITableView).

```
let cell = UITableViewCell()
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Hello World"
cell.contentView.addSubview(label)
label.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
    maker.centerX.centerY.equalToSuperview()
}
```

Above is all the code I set. The memory warning makes me a a little crazy. So how to get rid of it ?

Comment: Are you sure it's related to SnapKit? Because, clearly, not coding the reusing of cells, is clearly not recommended.

Comment: Since there are only 5 cells in the project, it shouldn't be a problem of reusing of cell. When I comment the last 3 lines of code above, the memory warning just disappear. How to explain it ?

Comment: I have updated the sample project. It fully explains my problem right now.

Comment: Could this be related: https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/issues/310 ?